# How can the colour profile be selected for images generated by Image Capture?

Tags: macos, color, scanning

I'm scanning photos using the Image Capture app and would like it to generate images with a colour space/profile other than sRGB, which it seems to default to. There doesn't appear to be any way to specify a colour profile in the Image Capture UI itself.

It seems that it's [possible to change the default colour profile used for a device using ColorSync](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/colorsync-utility/csync005/mac). For example, here I've selected the ProPhoto colour profile as the default for my Canon LiDE 220 scanner:

[image: ColorSync device colour profile UI]

But when I open Image Capture, it resets the default colour space back to sRGB.

While experimenting, I've found that if I change the scanner's profile in ColorSync while ImageCapture is open, the generated images are tagged with the colour profile I selected, but the actual pixel data in the image is actually still sRGB, so the image colours are just distorted.

I am able to use the ScanGear software provided by Canon to generate images in a specific colour space, but ScanGear is somewhat clunky/error prone (in terms of getting settings right), and I'm trying to get a non-technical person set up to do their scanning, and Image Capture seems a better fit for them if I can get it to do what I want.

Edit:

My reasoning for wanting to not scan to sRGB is based on an assumption that the scanner can produce a wider range of colours than sRGB can represent. I found the input profile for my scanner and it is indeed wider than sRGB (although who knows what range of that garmut the scanner can actually produce in practice):
[image: input profile for my scanner compared to sRGB]

Comment: Can I ask what you are actually trying to achieve by this? Trying to lift an sRGB image to ProPhoto will gain no new information (& will incidentally not be viewable correctly on most screens). A printer/scanner cannot even manage the sRGB gamut, let alone such as P3 or ProPhoto. inks simply are nowhere near as wide as digital images can be. It all leaves me wondering … what's the point? What are you actually trying to do? The 'correct' profile for any device is its native profile, or custom if the device has been professionally calibrated.

Comment: I'm assuming the scanner has a wider gamut than sRGB so I want to get the data from the scanner without squeezing it into sRGB. I guess I could probably find the scanner's profile and see if it actually is wider.

Comment: I found the scanner's input profile and added a screenshot comparing it to sRGB.

Comment: OK, that's starting to make more sense - but you can't just switch it to any old profile, you can only switch it to the scanner's **correct** profile. Whether that actually works I cannot tell. Ironically, my scanner's device profile is actually sRGB. HP laserjet, officey, not photographic. If i change it, scans still come in tagged as sRGB.

Comment: I'm looking to control the output profile used to encode the data of the generated image (which can be any arbitrary profile), not the scanner's own input profile (which indeed must match the scanner). The output profile can be device agnostic (like sRGB or ProPhoto) — it need not have any relation to the scanner.

Comment: You're not going to get profile conversion out of something so basic as Image Capture. It's designed to get the image in, not manipulate it. However, as I said before, upscaling the profile is not going to gain anything except empty numbers or an actual compression of your data. If you're moving this data into Photoshop etc, then you want to import with the correct hardware profile attached & not convert until Export As... so you only get one conversion & preserve your original data at all times. (This is assuming the rest of your workflow is correctly calibrated.)

Comment: I agree, but that's the problem though. I can't get the image data out of Image Capture in the hardware profile. Image Capture internally is converting from the scanner's colour space/profile into sRGB before giving me the image, so the data is gone before I can get at it.

Comment: I very much doubt it is converting anything. Best would be 'ignoring' or simply re-tagging. Compare images from Image Capture to one from Canon's own software. Get them into something reliable like photoshop & soft-proof one to the other.